# Optimizing the infragistics wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, optimization, datagrid, infragistics

I should start out with the disclaimer that I don't have a lot of info into this problem, but I wanted to put a feeler out to see if anyone else had this problem. I started a new job and some folks here are using Infragistics WPF datagrid. The grid was selected because of the visual flexibility, but apparently when there are large amounts of rows in the grid, things begin to perform very poorly. This is possibly due to implementation (not sure, haven't gotten into the code yet) and shouldn't be taken as a negative on the control.

Has anyone else encountered and have any advice I could pass onto the developers? Thanks in advance.

Edit*: I think introducing paging might not be an option. The grid is being used in such a capacity that it is displaying data streamed into it. So the use case is that the end user is monitoring 50-100 rows that are updating with new values intra-second (aka - think running stock tickers instead of flipping through a result set)

Comment: how do you provide the data to the datagrid?
Are you using a PagedCollectionView? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.pagedcollectionview(VS.95).aspx

Comment: You know, I'm not sure. But I think paging might not be an acceptable solution. I'll edit the original statement to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having problems with XamDataGrid as well. Although I don't have the right version to attempt this, you might try changing to the high-performance hoverless style, and suppressing events, as described here:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/48307/264160.aspx

The rest of the suggestions are a lot more specific and handle particular schemas and use-cases.

Here's a bit more of an overview of Infragistics optimizations:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2010.3/CLR4.0/?page=xamData_Performance_Optimizations_Overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Xceed DataGrid, but I recently discovered our DataGrid was binding to a View (DataGridCollectionView) and not to a datasource (DataView/DataTable).

This meant we replaced the entire view for each refresh.

By binding to a DataTable, my code now refreshes the DataGrid instantly with a few thousand rows where it use to take 1-2 seconds.

As most grids are similar. please verify how your code is binding to the data that goes into your DataGrid.

I posted some code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792158/xceed-datagrid-resets-scrollbar-position/3478144#3478144) in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is take is to enable virtualisation - this ensure that only the information on the screen is involved in a repaint. See no problem with 100 rows being continuously updated.